# Object apache is not a member of package org

Tags: scala

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.Project

object HelloWorld {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
      println("Hello, world!")
   }
}
```

I tried to run this code using following command:

```
java -cp D:\tools\apache-ant-1.7.0\lib\ant.jar;D:\tools\scala-2.9.1.final\lib\scala-compiler.jar;D:\tools\scala-2.9.1.final\lib\scala-library.jar -Dscala.usejavacp=true scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner D:\test\scala\ant.scala
```

**There is following error:**

```
D:\test\scala\ant.scala:1: error: object apache is not a member of package org
import org.apache.tools.ant.Project
           ^
one error found
```

What is wrong?

**UPDATE:**
As I can see it is impossible to import any org.xxx package.
The same problem with javax.xml.xxx package.

```
D:\test\test2.scala:2: error: object crypto is not a member of package javax.xml
import javax.xml.crypto.Data
                 ^
one error found
```

Actually I cannot import anything!

```
D:\test\test3.scala:3: error: object test is not a member of package com
import com.test.utils.ant.taskdefs.SqlExt
           ^
one error found
```

Comment: Don't you need to put the -cp content in quotes? E.g. -cp "D:\tools\apache-ant-1.7.0\lib\ant.jar;..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experimented with `scala.bat` (uncommenting the echo of the final command line, see the line starting with `echo "%_JAVACMD%" ...`) and found that this should work:

```
java -Dscala.usejavacp=true -cp d:\Dev\scala-2.9.1.final\lib\scala-compiler.jar;d:\Dev\scala-2.9.1.final\lib\scala-library.jar scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner -cp d:\Dev\apache-ant-1.8.2\lib\ant.jar D:\test\scala\ant.scala
```

Answer (score 3):

You haven't included the ant jar file in your classpath.

The compiler effectively builds objects representing the nested package structure. There is already a top-level package named org from the JDK (org.xml for example) but without additional jars org.apache is not there.

Comment: Sorry. I've put wrong commad to my message. Corrected. ant.jar is in classpath.

Answer (score 2):

I found that in general when an error of type `Object XXX is not a member of package YYY` occurs, you should:

Check that all your files are in a package, ie. not in the top-level `src/` directory

Answer (score 0):

I would check that 'D:\tools\apache-ant-1.7.0\lib\ant.jar' exist and also check that it is not  corrupt (length 0 or unable to open with 'jar tf D:\tools\apache-ant-1.7.0\lib\ant.jar').

Comment: ant.jar exists and is not corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Run with scala command instead:

scala -cp D:\tools\apache-ant-1.7.0\lib\ant.jar;D:\tools\scala-2.9.1.final\lib\scala-compiler.jar;D:\tools\scala-2.9.1.final\lib\scala-library.jar D:\test\scala\ant.scala